# E: Package 'openssh-server' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, updates, ssh

I try to us Xshell to connect the windows and Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) installed in VirtualBox. but recently, they cannot communicate with each other. I shut down the firewall and used the "host-only" model, NAT and Bridge model. still doesn't work. someone suggested installing the ssh, and I found the openssh-client has been installed, but the openssh-server has not been installed, so I tried to install the openssh-server by commandline

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`,

and the problems came as below:
**

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Package openssh-server is not available, but is referred to by another
package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'openssh-server' has no installation candidate
```

**
I tried to use "sudo apt-get update" and another question happened as following"

**

```
sudo apt-get update 
Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease   Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com' 
Err:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
  Temporary failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com' > 
Reading package lists...Done> 
W: Failed to fetch
http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary
failure resolving 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com' 
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease 
  Temporary failure resolving 'dl.google.com'  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.**
```

I changed the source, for instance, main source or Canda source. but doesn't work. 
I appreciate it so much who would like to give any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You seem to be having trouble connecting to the Ubuntu repositories - can you try using a different server?

Comment: Thanks, you mean I may change the source? tried, still not work.